# Object Reference Exception

Tags: c#, sql, .net, exception

Can anyone help me with this issue. i am trying to insert data in a local DB from my .NET app but it throws me Object Reference Exception. You can se my code below:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rights"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string insert = "insert into userinfo(Name,Mbiemri) values (@Name,@Mbiemri)";
            SqlCommand cnd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);

            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mbiemri", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }
    }
```

and i think that this is the line that throws the exception 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rights"].ConnectionString);

please give me some solution cuz there are days i am working with this.

Comment: Hint - what is `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rights"]` is null?

Comment: Then the likely problem is the connectionstrings portion...

Comment: @GiladGreen I have no idea why that row is null. i have used the same soloution in different programs and worked just fine

Comment: @Lara - that is why you need to debug and find the case when it fails and why :) the dup question explains it all

Comment: Are you have connection string name "Rights" using `<add name="Rights" connectionString="..." />` in app/web.config?

Comment: @Lara Can you post the web.config part here.

Comment: @Sanrar Raj  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="AdventureWorks2014ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQL08R2E_UAT;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @Lara As you said you are trying to connect local DB. Then your LocalDB ConStr should be `<add name="Rights" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Data‌​base1.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` Problem is you have no ConStr with name of `Rights`. This the cause of `Object Reference Exception`.

Comment: @SankarRaj i alredy tried this and leads me to this error                      
 HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: @Lara This is your next problem. You have not configured `Default Document` in IIS. You should fix the ConStr error first, Then look into this.