# How to get the value dynamically created checkbox value in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm adding checkbox controls dynamically in asp.net gridview like this:

```
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(cb1);
```

And I want to access whether that checkbox is checked or not on button click event...

on button click I have tried this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in grdreport.Rows)
{
    if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cb1");
        // cb1.Checked = true;
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object cb1 value is null

Comment: Hi @Nivas. When you run your program , right click on page and look at source , or use similar tool to do so. You will be able to verify what name your control actually has.

Comment: @Alicia after inspect page the control name show is cb1

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdreport.Rows)
{

    CheckBox checkbox1= (row.Cells[3].FindControl("cb1") as CheckBox);
    if (checkbox1.Checked)
                        {

                        }
}
```

There is a need to access the checkbox trough a specific row and cell

Comment: still same error  'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: 'foreach (GridViewRow row in grdreport.Rows)
        {

            
                CheckBox checkbox1 = (row.Cells[3].FindControl("cb1") as CheckBox);
                // cb1.Checked = true;
                if (checkbox1.Checked)
                {
                }
            
        }'.

Comment: @NivasKhatal When are you adding the check boxes, on poageload?

Comment: No i dont add it on page load

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object cb1 value is null

Comment: do the check boxes exist before the button click event when do you add them to your page? @NivasKhatal

Comment: yes checkbox exist before button click and i am adding them on rowdatabound event

Answer (score 0):

Focus on this line:

```
 CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cb1");
```

First check if `item.FindControl("cb1")` is giving you any value or not. More Info - [Object Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764756/object-reference-exception)

Comment: cb1 is giviing null value

Comment: still same error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 0):

When checkbox or any object is added dynamically to Gridview during RowDataBound(), and if the value of that dynamic object should be retrieved on button click, enable view state for that object during RowDataBound() and it works like a charm.

```
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
**cb1.EnableViewState = true;**
row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(cb1);
```